# B2C: make password field visible?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there any way to make the password field text in B2C login (local account) visible to the user (show pwd kind of thing)? I cannot use JS so the usual approaches do not seem possible.

Comment: As I know, you cannot set the password visible in the portal for the security reason.

Comment: Just to be clear: I did not mean 'permanently visible' but 'visible at user request', e.g. how you can do it when signing to Hotmail - there is a little icon on the right hand side of the password field, which when pressed displays the currently entered string.